# word order with as and multiple adjectives and an article and a noun

Tags: adjectives

I found a sentence. 'It is as good a racy, romantic historical novel as one could hope to find.'.
Is the word order of 'as good a racy, romantic historical novel' right?
I'm dubious of the location of the article 'a' between good and racy. Shouldn't it go between historical and novel?

Comment: The first _as_ isn't part of the noun phrase; instead, it belongs to the _as ... as_ construction.

Comment: For regular readers, both answers contradict the conclusion of ELU Q.113060   This (or "this car") is as good as a car gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three examples of the uncomplicated sentence.

> [“now is as good a time as any”.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/as-good-a-time-place-etc-as-any)
>   "And I can make just as good a cake as you can." PBMullen *Old Voices*
>   'It is as good a novel as one could hope to find.'

If you want to say the cake is a chocolate sponge; or
if you want to say the novel is a 'racy, romantic historical' novel, they become

> "And I can make just as good a *chocolate sponge* cake as you can."
>   "It is as good a *racy, romantic historical* novel as one could hope to find."

The adjectives go in the usual place, just before the noun.